# Meaning of Population is growing at some specific rate

Tags: derivatives

Can anyone please tell me what is the meaning of the following line ?

**Population is growing at some specific rate**

I think it means $\frac{dy}{dt} = k$ where $y $  is the population at time $t$ and $k$ is a constant.

Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, you are. However, a point to be taken care of - when the population is growing, the derivative is positive, and when it is declining, it is negative.

Comment: Very often the rate constant k is part of the growth (positive k) or decay (negative k) equation $\frac{dy}{dt} = ky$.